# What is the one word for doll witch

Tags: single-word-requests

There are stories where children find a doll on the road. They take it home, and then all sorts of problems start in their families. What is one word for such witchy dolls  ?

Answer (score 4):

It's a [***maumet***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/maumet) (mammet, mommet)...

> *a doll, puppet, scarecrow, or other figure built to resemble a human being.*
>    Obsolete: *an idol; a false god.*

Etymology from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mammet)...

> *C13: from Old French **mahomet**  idol,
>
>    literally: the prophet Mohammed, from the belief that his image was worshipped.*

It could also be called a [***gris-gris***](http://www.themystica.com/mystica/articles/g/gris-gris.html), particularly in the context of [Juju](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juju) (origin uncertain, but may refer to the French word *joujou*, which meant "doll" or "plaything").

---

For an adjectival form,...

> "This doll is [**possessed**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/possessed)!"
>   *- influenced or controlled by something (as **an evil spirit**, a passion, or an idea)*

Comment: The above is correct. Also, the word *totem* is used to describe any toy/trinket object that is somehow enchanted (with benevolence, neutrality, or malevolence alike) and non-toy trinkets as well as jewelry of enchantment can be called *talismans*

Comment: Also to back up: [**poppet**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/poppet) - "small human figure used in witchcraft and sorcery," c.1300, early form of puppet (q.v.). - And here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppet

Comment: _Cursed_ is also good for an adjective.

Comment: I have to agree, though, that of all the adjectives recommended here, "cursed" is probably the best.

Comment: @Brad: Good point. But it's worth noting that Google Books has 10 times more ***doll is possessed*** than ***doll is cursed***. On the other hand, there are 3 times more ***ring is cursed*** than ***ring is possessed***. That's because *possessed* is more appropriate to human or *human-like* "vessels", whereas *cursed* can apply to just about anything (even abstracts, such as *love, hunger,* or *ambition*).

Comment: @miercoledi: I did think about words like *totem* and *talisman* - they certainly have the advantage of being far more common than *maumet/mommet*. They're also less "potentially offensive" in their etymology, but (and this may not be unconnected) they don't have very strong negative connotations - so in fact they're both becoming increasingly *positive* (I think they're getting more and more synonymous with ***mascot***).

Comment: i agree @FumbleFingers also a **maumet** (and i believe *poppet* may work as well) is specifically a representation of a human meant to somehow entrap or control, as with a **voodoo doll**, so i think **maumet** is the best answer.

Comment: @miercoledi: I only vaguely knew the word - and then only spelled as *mommet*, so I had to check Google Books counts to convince myself that *maumet* was more common. Personally, I'd call such a thing a *voodoo doll* (or more likely, a *doll that was possessed [by an evil spirit]*). But OP asked for "one word", so we are where we are. I do think *poppet* is a bit of a lost cause though - these days it's mainly a term of endearment, especially applied to young children - *"Ah! He's [such a poppet](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22such+a+poppet%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)!"*.

Answer (score 0):

Those dolls are HAUNTED or ENCHANTED, as in Robert the haunted/enchanted doll.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_the_Doll

Comment: *Haunted* is usually applied to things which are big enough for "life-size" evil spits (or actual people) to *be inside* (as in, *houses, castles*). And [*enchanted*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enchanted?show=0&t=1393085088) usually has positive connotations, not negative ones.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I urge you to read the link I've posted. Clearly it doesn't quite match your notion of "haunted" and "enchanted".

Comment: No disrespect, Louel, but I'm a competent native speaker. With words as common as these I'd rather trust my own intuitions than those implied by a badly-written Wikipedia page which is flagged as having "multiple issues".

Comment: And this video proves that native speakers from the US also use "haunted" for things that are not necessarily big enough for "life-size evil spirits (or actual people) to live inside." In this video, they use "haunted" to describe a painting. I'm sure you're familiar with the show Friends--and I hope a competent native speaker like you will find their English up too scratch. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnJyTsH5zsg

Comment: No disrespect, FumbleFingers, but the name was not invented by whoever wrote this Wikipedia article.. "Robert the Haunted Doll" is a name used by Americans (from Florida), who have every right to claim they are competent native speakers just as much as you do. I'm not saying you've been misusing the terms "enchanted" and "haunted". I'm just saying your notion of such words doesn't reflect how the words are used by other English speakers.Here are the links (not from Wiki):http://www.hauntedamericatours.com/hauntedstates/hauntedflorida/hauntedkeywest/ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffMwb1mAMv8

Comment: I think FumbleFingers is correct that _haunt_ properly refers to a spirit inhabiting a place, rather than possessing an item. However, I also think it's common to stretch the meaning to apply to similar things. Thus, something like a haunted painting or doll is understandable and acceptable, but also a bit marked and novel.

Comment: As I was saying, I don't question the fact that "haunted" collocates with "house" or "castle", but to say that it shouldn't be used to refer to smaller things, like a doll isn't quite right. I also agree that "enchanted" generally has a positive connotation, but to say that it has ONLY positive connotations is also wrong. Hence, in Merriam-Webster Unabridged, we see this sentence under the entry "enchanted"--a princess ENCHANTED by a cruel sorcerer. FumbleFingers, being a competent native speaker, has good reason to trust his own intuitions. But are the lexicographers of MW incompetent?

Comment: @Louel: Who brought MW into this? Note that their *noun* definition of ***haunt*** is *a **place** habitually frequented* - not an ***object***. And their definition of ***enchant*** (there's only the verb) is *to attract and hold the attention of (someone) by being interesting, pretty, etc.*. All of their example usages are "positive". Also note that I never said small objects *can't* be "haunted" - but it's a *very* rare usage. And even today (more so a couple of centuries ago), "enchantment" can be a *bad* thing. It's just a relatively unusual usage compared to *Enchanted* the Disney movie.

Comment: FumbleFingers: Have a look at Merriam-Webster Unabridged and you'll see that their first definition of "enchant" is 
:to influence by or as if by charms and incantation :  bewitch (a princess enchanted by a cruel sorcerer) Does the usage here seem positive to you? Anyway, all I wanted to do was to point out that other competent native speakers also use "haunted" and "enchanted" to describe a doll. I don't disagree with the other things you've written here.